# How to sort two dimensional array in Javascript using bubble sort?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Here is the original data, which is returned in ajax request:

```
{
    "oLB3ujqaG123xf--hVY223Oq1ZI": [
        45,
        "兔子",
        1430124206
    ],
    "oLB3ujl4555Ksj6UwTyK22242Y": [
        121,
        "燕子",
        1430191889
    ],
    "oLB3242SUyXKaaefwTyKKuN42Y": [
        11,
        "豹子",
        1430191889
    ]
}
```

I want it to be sorted by the first field of each item, the result should be:

```
{
    "oLB3242SUyXKaaefwTyKKuN42Y": [
        11,
        "豹子",
        1430191889
    ],
    "oLB3ujqaG123xf--hVY223Oq1ZI": [
        45,
        "兔子",
        1430124206
    ],
    "oLB3ujl4555Ksj6UwTyK22242Y": [
        121,
        "燕子",
        1430191889
    ] 
}
```

The way I tried is:

```
function sortFunction(a, b) {
    if (a[0] === b[0]) { return 0; }
    else {return (a[0] < b[0]) ? -1 : 1;}
}

// cacheData is the original data
cacheDataSorted = cacheData.sort(sortFunction);
```

It's not working, why?

Comment: hey first field is an array, so you want to sort based on the arrays? please clarify.

Comment: You can't call .sort on an object, it can only be called on an array.

Comment: @user2660816 but even I changed it to [] (array) not work too .

Comment: @hitman4890 I just want it be sorted, no matter if it's array or mixed object.

Comment: But you would still have an array of objects which their values being arrays, not just an array of arrays. So you would have to compare the values from inside the |k, v| v.

Comment: You cannot sort the properties of an object. If you want order you need an array.